# Best way to measure effectiveness of discrete wavelet denoising?

Tags: discrete-signals, wavelet, denoising, dwt

I am using matlab wavelet toolbox to denoise physiological signals, I am plotting the denoised signal on top of the original noisy signal and making sure spikes were not removed as a measure of effectiveness as well as plotting the FFT of the two signals (original and denoised).

Is this a correct way to check my results of DWT denoising?
I saw some paper using mean squared error and SNR as a check.

Comment: "correct": well, that depends on what you want to use that effectiveness measure for!

Comment: I want to make sure my signals of interest are not affected by the denoising rather only the noise is flattened or attenuated

Comment: Well, I guess if your signal of interest is these spikes?

Comment: I am still working on appropriate quality metrics for sparse signals, after all these years